# Failing to run Java Springboot app with Swagger3

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger-ui, swagger-3.0

I'm running a SpringBoot (2.2.2.RELEASE) java application with `springfox.boot.starter:3.0.0` and when I run it locally from within my Eclipse IDE it works well. The problem is that when I package it as Docker image and run the container then when I try to run `http://localhost:8089/swagger-ui/#` it displays the default `Swagger Petstore` example.

Here is my Docket @Bean:

```
@Configuration
public class SwaggerConfig {

  @Bean
  public Docket api() { //
    return new Docket(DocumentationType.OAS_30) //
        .apiInfo(DEFAULT_API_INFO) //
        .select() //
        .paths(PathSelectors.regex("/error").negate()) //
        .build();
  }
}
```

Obviously it's something related to running it from within a docker container, any idea what's missing to make it work?

Thank you!

**EDIT:**

Probably worth mentioning that I use to work with `springfox:2.9.2` and it worked well both locally and as Docker container.

Answer (score 0):

I think u must use `http://localhost:8089/swagger-ui.html` instead of `http://localhost:8089/swagger-ui/#`, this might work.